# Magento- configurable products options order to match the order they are in the attribute set

Tags: magento

I have a magento site I'm building (1.6) my site has a bunch of configurable options with 6 or so attributes set as dropdowns for the customer to pick from. After saving a configurable product the order of the attributes changes. I've been able to find what I think is happening, it is reordering them according to the attribute id not the order I have them set up in the attribute set. I need to find a way to get magento to keep the order of the attributes the same as they are in the attribute set. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Trick is pretty simple.
Just drag'n'drop them in product->edit->associatedProduct tab ;)
The order of attributes from this page is saved to catalog_product_super_attribute table.

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with that, unfortunatly something is up and I can only drag and drop the top 1 out of 6, the others won't move by that method. I'm hoping there is a way to code in to set up the order the same way it is in the attribute set it's just above me.

Comment: or would there be a way to edit that table via .csv file? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Well, You know attribute_id of every super attribute in configurable product?
if you do run following query for every attribute
UPDATE catalog_product_super_attribute SET position = 1 WHERE attribute_id = 'your_attribute_id'
you can order them.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for the same and finally i found this and it works for me hope it will work for others too.

From <kbd>Admin Panel</kbd> > <kbd>Catalog</kbd> > <kbd>Attributes</kbd> > <kbd>Manage Attributes</kbd> select the one like if you want to make it like for the capacity `4GB > 8GB > 16GB` and so on then do this small changes.

Select <kbd>Manage Label / Options</kbd> > <kbd>Manage Options</kbd> (values of your attribute) and if you already created the variables just add the position manually, like:

> 4GB - 1
>   8GB - 2
>   16GB - 3

Save and flush the cache.
That's it, now it should show the attributes as per the position that you assign.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old question but I have found a solution right now having the same problem.

If you are still interesting in changing the order of the configurable attribute you may want to look into this method:

- `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable::getConfigurableAttributes()`
  `getConfigurableAttributes()` load the collection of attributes.

*The first time the collection is loaded, before saving the configurable, there is no `position` value, so I think the attribute ID rules on the display order.

If you want to alter this order you can only add a sort for `attribute_id` **after** the `->orderByPosition()` and revert the order ( this will preserve the `position` functionality )*

For example, here I have added `->setOrder('attribute_id','DESC')`

```
public function getConfigurableAttributes($product = null)
    {
        Varien_Profiler::start('CONFIGURABLE:'.__METHOD__);
        if (!$this->getProduct($product)->hasData($this->_configurableAttributes)) {
            $configurableAttributes = $this->getConfigurableAttributeCollection($product)
                ->orderByPosition()
                ->setOrder('attribute_id','DESC')
                ->load();
            $this->getProduct($product)->setData($this->_configurableAttributes, $configurableAttributes);
        }
        Varien_Profiler::stop('CONFIGURABLE:'.__METHOD__);
        return $this->getProduct($product)->getData($this->_configurableAttributes);
    }
```

**OR**

In case you want to modify the order in more radical way, you can also act on this method:

- `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config::getAttributesJson()`

This is basically calling the `getConfigurableAttributes()`.

To understand if this is the first configurable load, you can check all the attributes in the array `$attributes` to see if they **all** have a position `==0` and then proceed with a manual reorder )

**Example**
I'm omitting all the module creation and the rewrite part.

Here an example modifying `getAttributesJson()` in order to have the color attribute always on the top.

```
 public function getAttributesJson()
{
    $attributes = $this->_getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)
        ->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($this->_getProduct());
    if (!$attributes) {
        return '[]';
    } else {
        // == START ==
        // checking if I can re-order
        if ($this->isNoSavedPosition($attributes)) {
            $attributes = $this->attributeReorder($attributes);
        }
        // == END ==

        // Hide price if needed
        foreach ($attributes as &$attribute) {
            if (isset($attribute['values']) && is_array($attribute['values'])) {
                foreach ($attribute['values'] as &$attributeValue) {
                    if (!$this->getCanReadPrice()) {
                        $attributeValue['pricing_value'] = '';
                        $attributeValue['is_percent'] = 0;
                    }
                    $attributeValue['can_edit_price'] = $this->getCanEditPrice();
                    $attributeValue['can_read_price'] = $this->getCanReadPrice();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($attributes);
}

public function isNoSavedPosition($attributes)
{
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if (isset($attribute['position']) && $attribute['position'] != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // there is no position saved
    // - this is the first time the configurable is loaded
    // - (the position is saved on second save action)
    return true;
}

public function attributeReorder($attributes)
{
    // we want the Color attribute to be always on the top
    $newAttributesOrderArray = array();

    foreach ($attributes as $key => $attribute) {
        if (isset($attribute['label']) && $attribute['label'] == 'Color') {
            $newAttributesOrderArray[] = $attribute;
            unset($attributes[$key]);
        }
    }
    $newAttributesOrderArray = array_merge($newAttributesOrderArray,$attributes);
    return $newAttributesOrderArray;
}
```